# Perguntas referentes a ambientes e problemas computacionais estão no escopo da Comunidade?

Tags: debate

Minha dúvida é essa mesma que está no título. Por exemplo, eu gostaria de saber de outros desenvolvedores quais ações são tomadas diante de uma determinada situação gerada por um sistema desenvolvido por eles mesmo.

Eu desenvolvo um sistema, coloco em produção e fico responsável por sua manutenção. Então o sistema começa a apresentar um erro ou quedas em produção que não são replicadas em ambientes de homologação ou desenvolvimento. Diante desse cenário, é escopo fazer uma pergunta para saber quais procedimentos as pessoas da comunidade tomam para tentar resolver esse tipo de problema.

Talvez não tenha código uma pergunta dessas, pois já é "um passo a frente" do desenvolvimento puro. Mas pode haver outros materiais como logs, estatísticas de acessos, configuração de servidores...

Mas a questão é, está no escopo esse tipo de pergunta? Ou é estritamente programação?

Comment: [acho](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272/3117) que é off-topic, procure os outros assuntos e veja se tem algum que sua pergunta se encaixaria

Answer (score 7):

Depende muito como o problema é formulado e se ele tem uma resposta.

Tem muita gente que chega e diz: *"o meu tomcat fica travando, me ajudem"*. Ninguém, eu acho, tem uma boal de cristal.

Cabe ao OP colher e disponibilizar as informações técnicas necessárias. Se ele conseguir expor o cenário de forma clara, até onde ele chegou na análise do problema, e demonstrar que realmente se esforçou, tenho certeza que o pessoal vai se interessar.

Problemas de produção podem ser oriundos de falhas de *design* e *programação*, tais como:

- Escolha do escopo incorreto para armazenar variáveis (session, request, cookies), etc.
- Falha no fechamento de recursos utilizados: conexão de banco, arquivos, etc.
- Problemas de concorrência em ambientes multi-threading.

Para mim, pelo menos, perguntas desse tipo são relevantes porque, quando identificadas e resolvidas em produção, nos ajudam também no desenvolvimento de novos sistemas. Além disso, o conhecimento sobre sistemas de terceiros me permite analisar e comparar a abordagem utilizada com o que tenho visto.

Enfim, isso agrega experiências diferentes sem que eu precise efetivamente trabalhar em outra empresa ou projeto